# C# Creating an Expression in runtime with a string

Tags: c#, linq, runtime, expression

So let's say that I have a method of the following manners:

```
public T Get<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expr) {
    // use the expression to retrieve cool stuff.
}
```

Now I want to invoke this method with only string values. That is, I need to compile an expression in runtime.

So, let's say that I have a class Foo:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then have another class Bar:

```
public class Bar {
    public string AnotherName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to compile an expression that would look like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo { Name = "AName" };
Expression<Func<Bar, string>> expr = p => p.AnotherName == foo.Name;
```

However, the only information I got in runtime is:

- The name of the property "AnotherName"
- The name of the class "Bar"
- The value of the property "Name" in Foo
- The name of the class "Foo"

So, after some lurking I found out that there is a System.Linq.Dynamic library where I could compile an expr of the string:

```
@"Bar.AnotherName == AName";
```

Example:

```
var sourceValue = "AName";
var targetClassName = "Bar";
var targetPropertyName = "AnotherName";

var expr = string.Format("{0}.{1} == {2}", 
    targetClassName, targetPropertyName, sourceValue);

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Bar), "Target");
var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expr);
var lambda = e.Compile();
```

However, this will only result in a delegate to a lambda expression.

My question is now, is it actually possible to invoke the Get method by creating an expression in runtime like this?

Comment: Search for `CSharpCodeProvider`. Maybe overkill, but it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need dynamic:

```
var sourceValue = "AName";

// You will need the namespace of Bar here!
var namespaceTargetClassName = "ExpressionProblem";
var targetClassName = "Bar";
var targetPropertyName = "AnotherName";

{
    var targetType = Type.GetType(namespaceTargetClassName + "." + targetClassName);
    var p = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "Target");
    var pr = Expression.PropertyOrField(p, targetPropertyName);
    var e = Expression.Equal(pr, Expression.Constant(sourceValue));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(e, p); // It would be an Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>
}
```

Note that this first solution has a problem: the delegate type you are generating is a `Func<targetClassName, bool>`, so you can't easily compile and use it.

It's easier to create a `Func<object, bool>` that internally does the cast.

```
{
    var targetType = Type.GetType(namespaceTargetClassName + "." + targetClassName);
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "Target");

    // I'm using the as operator here, if you prefer a "strong" 
    // cast (the cast operator that throws if the object is of
    // invalid type), use Expression.Convert with the same syntax 
    var pcasted = Expression.TypeAs(p, targetType); 
    var pr = Expression.PropertyOrField(pcasted, targetPropertyName);
    var e = Expression.Equal(pr, Expression.Constant(sourceValue));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(e, p);

    Func<object, bool> func = lambda.Compile();

    Bar obj = new Bar { AnotherName = "AName" };
    bool res = func(obj);
}
```